# Std vector of std matrices (vector of vectors) in c++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a std vector of vectors say A, defined as;

```
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > A (6,std::vector<double>(6));
```

and I would like to create another vector (say of size 8 called QQ) in which each row I would like to store
my vector of vectors A, B, C ... etc all with same size (6x6).

Anyone knows how to initialise vector QQ and reach indexes of it ?

Comment: It would be most useful for you to show what you've already tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: Here, read a good reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector. And remember a vector of vectors of vectors is still a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A three dimensional vector follows the same format that a 2 dimension vector has.  If A, B, C ... are defined as

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > A (6,std::vector<double>(6));
```

Then their type is `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`.  To create a vector that will hold 8 of those then you need to use

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> someName(8);
```

If you want to have the whole thing initialized at one time then the syntax becomes:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> someName(8, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(6,std::vector<double>(6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this?

```
 vector<vector< vector<double> > >
                QQ(8, (vector<vector<double> >
                   (6,vector<double>(6,-5))));
                                        ^
                                    initialize here
```